# How to configure a VLAN on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, vlan, windows-8.1

Basically there is a media converter installed at my customer and from this media converter there is an UTP cable to my network adapter. 
This circuit is delivered to me with a VLAN(tagged) and to test it I need to set a VLAN in my network adapter or find another similar solution.

Do you guys know how to set that?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You need a network adaptor that allow to tag a VLAN.

A bit like shown into that pic below. (found [there](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/usb-to-ethernet-adapter-supporting-multiple-virtual-lans))

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it seems that my adapter does not allow me to tag a VLAN. 

Is there another way to configure? Using a software or something like this?

Comment: Check for newer drivers for your NIC, or it may be unsupported on your hardware.

Comment: Do you need only a "test"? A one-shot check, I mean? Or it has to be left connected, for production purposes?

Comment: There is another way indeed. It is to use Hyper-V virtual switch which can be configured to request VLAN tagging of outgoing traffic.